# Files get renamed when transferring them from a PC to a Mac

Tags: macos, mac, filenames

I have a ton of files that I transfer from a PC to a Mac. I transfer them using a USB drive but when I put them in the Mac, a few of the filenames are changed.

For example if I have this file:

```
P001_img_tommarow_graphic.png
```

It may get changed to something like:

```
P014AD~1.png
```

Does anyone know why something like this would happen?

Out of the 1000+ files I transfer it only happens to about 10 of them.

Answer (score 1):

The file system of your USB drive is using 8+3 (8 letters plus 3 letter extension) filenames natively (even though on Windows you can see the 'extended' long filenames).

One way around this could be to format the USB drive as FAT32...

Comment: I dont think that was the problem because
1. I have files with much longer names that are fine.
2. I tried it and it didnt change anything.

Thanks for the suggestion though.